# Insert Buttons to DataTables Cells fail to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to insert buttons into the JQuery DataTables but it seems that when the button is pressed, nothing happen.

The code as follows (for the JQuery Datatable):

```
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "aaData": movieclips,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "fnInitComplete": function() {
                                var oSettings = this.fnSettings();
                                for ( var i=0 ; i<oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length ; i++ ){
                                    if(oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch.length>0){
                                        $("tfoot input")[i].value = oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch;
                                        $("tfoot input")[i].className = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                "aoColumns": [
                    { 
                        "sTitle": "Title", 
                        "sClass": "center",
                        "sWidth": "80%"
                    },
                    { 
                        "sTitle": "Video URL",
                        "sClass": "center",
                        "fnRender": function(obj) {
                            var sReturn = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];
                            var returnButton = "<input class='approveButton' type='button' name='" + sReturn + "' value='Play'></input>";
                            return returnButton;
                        },
                        "sWidth": "20%"
                    }
                ]
            } );
```

The approveButton function as follows:

```
        $(".approveButton").click(function() {
            alert(this.name);

           try {
              alert(this.name);
           } finally {
              return false;
           }
        }
```

Any Insight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you assign the handler with `$(".approveButton").click(...)` it will only apply to elements that already exist which match the `".approveButton"` selector at that moment. That is, elements created later will not automatically get handlers of their own. I'm assuming that that is the problem - if not you can disregard the following...

Fortunately there is a mechanism for creating a handler that will automatically work on matching elements that are created in the future:

```
$(document).on("click", ".approveButton", function() {
   // your function code here
});
```

Notice that the initial selector is `document` - this will work, but you should set it up on a parent element closer to your buttons if you can, so perhaps the following:

```
$("#example").on("click", ".approveButton", function() { /* your code */ });
```

(I'm not sure if "#example" is the most appropriate parent for this purpose, but you don't show any of your HTML, so...)

Have a look at [the jQuery doco for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information.

Or, if you're using a version of jQuery older than 1.7 you can use [`.delegate()'](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Marked correct as information was quite comprehensive. If included the live() by Nicola, it would be prefect.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) because `.delegate()` is a better option unless you are still on a version < 1.4.2, but I guess 1.4.2 was less than two years ago so earlier version are probably still in use. Oh well, it's been mentioned now...

Answer (score 3):

If you use jquery < 1.7 you should use  [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or live()

```
    $(".approveButton").live('click', function() {
        alert(this.name);

       try {
          alert(this.name);
       } finally {
          return false;
       }
    }

    $("body").delegate(".approveButton", "click", function() {
        alert(this.name);

       try {
          alert(this.name);
       } finally {
          return false;
       }
    }
```

otherwise use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as suggested by nnnnnn